# How to make python open command reuse info

Tags: python

Hello I made a login system which stores usernames and password but it currently only holds one and every time I add a new one it deletes the old one how could I make so it continuously adds more to the list here is my code

```py
def register_user():
   username_info = username.get()
   password_info = password.get()
 
   file = open("info.txt","w")
   file.write('username= '+username_info + "\n")
   file.write('password= '+password_info)
   file.close()
```

Comment: The "mode" argument should be "a" instead of "w". Other modes can be found in the Python documentation.

Comment: Change the ```"w"``` argument to ```"a"```.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Open it in append mode with `"a"`:

```
file = open("info.txt","a")
```

Other modes can be found in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).